# How to use an external variable in MongoDB 'where' query via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB query that searches all properties for a value defined in the search variable. It works the following way:

```
 db.collection.findOne({
                $where: function() {
                    var search = 'searchstring';
                    for (var key in this) {
                        if (this[key] === search) {
                          return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

However, I would like to define the search variable outside the query.

But when I do so, I get an error that it is not referenced (i.e. scoping issue):

```
"ReferenceError: search is not defined near '[key] === search
```

How can I use or pass the variable to the query filter?

Comment: And where would that variable be defined in regards to the query above? The only solution is to define the variable *in scope* ?

Comment: Can you explain the logic of that `for` loop first?

Comment: You cannot. The function gets executed at the server side. The variable you declare resides on the client.

Comment: @SoluableNonagon The for loop simply iterates over all properties at the top level of the collection and checks if the property value is equal to the searchstring.

Comment: @adeneo I would like to use it like that: 

`var search = 'searchstring';
db.collection.findOne({
                $where: function() {
                    for (var key in this) {
                        if (this[key] === search) {
                          return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });`

Comment: @BatScream But how would anybody ever run dynamic queries if this wasn't possible?

Comment: Mongo does not let you search across all fields, you have to specify all the fields. You simply can't loop `this` and expect the keys to work, as `this` points to a Mongo document rather than just a JSON object. So to fix the loop, define an array with all the keys you want to search through, and loop that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search` is a variable that you define in your client, may be the shell, or any client API.

The function that you define for the `$where` clause, will not be executed on the client side, but on the `mongodb` server. 
so, when the function is being interpreted in the server side and it looks for the `search` variable, it was never defined on the server and hence you get the error.

In your case, you want the variable `search`, to be replaced with its content, by the client, before being executed on the server. And this is not possible, unless you build the function content itself in the client side.

*The client never really interprets anything you write inside the anonymous function*. **The server does**. The error you see is from the server. You can validate it by firing this query and looking onto the server logs:

```
2015-12-22T19:03:44.011-0800 I QUERY    [conn1] assertion 16722 ReferenceError:
searc is not defined
    at _funcs1 (_funcs1:1:39) near 's.key === searc){retu'  ns:test.t query:{ $w
here: function (){if(this.key === searc){return true}} }
```

There is a better way to write what you wish to achieve using the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator.

```
var search = "title";
var find = {};
find[search] = {$exists:true};
db.collection.findOne(find);
```

This works, because, you build the query parameter fully on the client side, before passing it on to the `findOne()` method.

Answer (score 11):

You can try something like this:

```
var searchstring = 'whatever';
var params = {};
params.$where = 'function() {' +
    'var search = "' + searchstring + '";' +
    'for (var key in this) {' +
        'if (this[key] === search) {' +
            'return true;' +
        '}' +
        'return false;' +
    '}' +
'}';
db.collection.findOne(params);
```

(Stringify your function and concat with external variable)

Worked for me via mongoose

Comment: Injecting an opaque string in executable code, what could go wrong ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this solution as long as you're in control of your variables or sanitising your input properly!

Comment: Brilliant solution, Aida

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using mongodb map reduce and scope functionality. Scope allows you to pass variables into map reduce job.

```
function map() {
    for (var key in this) {
        if (this[key] === search) {
            return emit(this._id, this);
        }
    }
}

function reduce(key, values) {
    return values[0];
}


db.collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, {
        out: {inline: 1},
        scope: {
            search: 'searchstring'
        }
    }
);
```